# How to avoid duplicate column name on alter table add column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have an old CMS what I need to maintain. Now here is a (bad) solution, but risky to remove, so I want to fix the error messages in console log. Actually the errors shown in error.log only and it is irritating only for me... but maybe here is a simple soution.

So I have a `menu` table and run this MySQL command:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `menu` ADD COLUMN `group_id` BIGINT not null default '1';
```

This run every time I log in to the CMS. But the point is, I got this error message in error.log file:

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Duplicate column name 'group_id' at /var/www/...
```

The wierd part is I use the `IGNORE` keyword to avoid this message, but I still get the error message. (Anyway there is everything works fine, but my error.log have many line of messages like this.)

Can I avoid somehow this messages? Maybe can I test somehow the field is exists on the table?

Remove run SQL commands is not an option.

Comment: If you have not already reviewed it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169458/mysql-how-to-create-column-if-not-exists

Comment: forgive my curiosity but why do you need this DDL script to run every time you log in to CMS system?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu as I see this is the table structure updater logic. This CMS run under many websites, and if the developer modify the table structure he use this way to update in every single website's tables. As I said, this is a bad solution :) we're working on to replace this CMS to a new, better one, but this is not a simple thing.

Answer (score 2):

I understood that you may have different DDLs. If that is the case I suggest you to have table for versioning. By using this table you can have unique version number every time you have new DDL / DML script. Then you can check whether that version number exists in versions table and if it doesn't you can execute your DDL script and after that you need to insert version number to versions table.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @version_number VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'V10298492';
  DECLARE @VERSION_EXISTS INT ;

  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO @VERSION_EXISTS 
  FROM CMS_VERSION 
  WHERE VERSION_NUMBER = @version_number;

  IF (@VERSION_EXISTS = 0)
     RETURN;
  END IF;

  --DDL SCRIPT AFTER THIS POINT
  ...
  --END OF DDL SCRIPT

  INSERT INTO CMS_VERSION (VERSION_NUMBER) 
    VALUES (@version_number);
END;
```